# Difference of funcions converging in measure to the same function

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f_n \to h$ and $g_n \to h$ in measure. Is it true that $|f_n - g_n| \to 0$ in measure? I tried using the triangle inequality to get to this result, but it implies only that:
$$\{ x \in X: |f_n(x) - g_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} \supseteq \{x \in X: |f_n(x) - h(x)|\geq \alpha/2 \}\cap \{x \in X: |g_n(x) - h(x)|\geq \alpha/2\}$$
I don't know if this is true, I guess it must be - can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\{ x \in X: |f_n(x) - g_n(x)| \geq \alpha\}$$ $$ \subseteq \{x \in X: |f_n(x) - h(x)|\geq \alpha/2 \}\cup \{x \in X: |g_n(x) - h(x)|\geq \alpha/2\}$$ and hence

$$\mu\{ x \in X: |f_n(x) - g_n(x)| \geq \alpha\}$$ $$ \leq \mu(\{x \in X: |f_n(x) - h(x)|> \alpha/2 \})+\mu( \{x \in X: |g_n(x) - h(x)|\geq \alpha/2\}) \to 0.$$